# when button is clicked, Form is redirected to another page But Data is not updating

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router

I am giving details in the form and clicking the submit button to populate the data in next page..So, on submit button I have given Link to redirect to the next page.In that page the data should display..But before submission of the data, it is redirecting me to next page and the data I am not able to fetch,But once I refresh the page I am able to see the updated value, Same happening with DELETE button also.
Can you help me in this?? Thanks in Advance.

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             data:[],
              objEdit:obj
                   }
            }


handleInput(e){
    this.state.objEdit[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState({objEdit:this.state.objEdit})
}

updateUser = () =>{
    console.log(this.state.objEdit)
    this.state.objEdit.id=null
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/data/",this.state.objEdit).then(res=>{
        console.log()
         }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Error Occured")
    })
}         
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <div className="col-sm-4">

                    <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="fname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.fname} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="lname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.lname} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="tel">Tel</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Tel" value={this.state.objEdit.tel} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.address} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="fname">City</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.city} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="state">State</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="state" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.state} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="zip">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.zip} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>    
                {/* <button onClick={this.updateUser} type="button">Add</button> */}
               <Link to="/Form">  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.updateUser}>Submit</button></Link> 
                    </form>
                </div>

                </div> 

            // </div>
        )
    }
}

let obj={
    fname:"",
    lname:"",
    tel:"",
    address:"",
    city:"",
    state:"",
    zip:'',
    id:''
}

class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             data:[],

            }
            }
            componentDidMount(){
                fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(user => this.setState({data:user}))
            }
            editUser=(obj,index)=>{
                console.log(obj,index)
                this.setState({objEdit:obj})
            }
            deleteUser=(i)=>{
                console.log("deleteUser called",i)
                axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/data/"+this.state.data[i].id).then(res=>{
                    console.log()
                }).catch((error)=>{
                    console.log("Error Occured")
                })
            }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Tel</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Zip</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.data.map((obj,i)=>{
                            return <tr key={i}>{Object.keys(obj).map((property)=>{
                                return <td key={property}>{obj[property]}</td>

                            })}<td><button onClick={()=>{this.editUser(obj,i)}} className="btn btn-info">Edit</button></td>
                            <td><button onClick={()=>{this.deleteUser(i)}} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td></tr>
                        })}
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                </div>
                </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default Form;
```

When I Click on SUbmit Button, It should redirect me to next page with updated values And edit and delete button also should work properly without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `history` object of `react-router` to goto the next page after you get the response form the api call. When you use `Link`, it redirects to the page directly.

Also,

```
handleInput(e){
    this.state.objEdit[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState({objEdit:this.state.objEdit})
}
(and)
this.state.objEdit.id=null
```

Why are you even doing this? You shouldn't be mutating the state object.

```
handleInput(e){

    this.setState({
        objEdit:{...this.state.obj, [e.target.name] : e.target.value}
    })

}
```

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
.
.
.
updateUser = () =>{
    console.log(this.state.objEdit)
    // this.state.objEdit.id=null
    const objEdit = {...this.state.objEdit, id: null};
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/data/", objEdit).then(res=>{
        console.log(res)
         this.props.history.push('/Form')
         }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Error Occured")
    })
}  
.
.
.
// remove the Link. 
<button 
 type="button" 
 className="btn btn-primary" 
 onClick={this.updateUser}
>
  Submit
</button>
.
.
.
export default withRouter(App)
```

You can do the same for others.

Comment: My Edit and delete functionality is not working as excepted. Once I refresh the page only delete is working and edit is not working at all...
Can you help me in this... Thanks in Advance